# Прибавить к значению в базе данных

Tags: mysql, sql

При обновлении данных к примеру необходимо прибавить единицу к значению

```
`views` = views+1
```

Вопрос в том, возможно прибавить так, чтобы второй раз views не прописывать. К примеру как нибудь так

```
`views` += 1
```

Comment: нельзя (это не прикол)

Comment: Подобной инкрементации в MySQL нет

Comment: на сколько я знаю: нет

Comment: Основной вопрос: а зачем это? Есть синтаксис языка запросов, у него свои правила, не зря появившиеся, разве нет?

Comment: Сделать форк СУБД, сделать свой синтаксис с инкрементом.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не получится. Ведь если вы данный столбец используете как внешний ключ, например, то "поедет" целостность БД.
Для проведения операций с данными - используйте средства языков программирования.